# SQL Server AG Agent jobs running successfully on secondary replica

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server AG 2016 Environment.

We have 2 nodes(1,2)  and it is on standard edition. So secondary is not readable.

My issue is, we failover to 2 and failover back  to 1 last week.

Since then my agent jobs on both nodes are running successfully (1 is understandable as its primary) but it is also running successfully on 2 and actually updating some tables on 1.

My understanding is, if secondary is not readable, the agent job must fail on 2 which is not happening. I read few blogs which ask to add a step in every job. But why is the job successful on 2 if the db is not readable ? And when i change the agent job on 02 and use master as db, and add full name of the object (server.schema.objectname) in the command, it it failing now, but if i dont use master as db, it runs fine.

Comment: Did you every find out why this was the case?

Answer (score 1):

We discovered this on our servers yesterday, we have patched SQL 2016 CU4 last week. We have not found the root cause, but migrated all jobs to a third server acting as tsx job master for our two target servers. In this set-up the jobs on the inactive node behaves as expected; They cannot run

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I run into this situation, too.
It seems an old publication was dwelling in the distributor.
Old jobs still running.
When you delete a publication, verify it is really dead.