# MSSQL Secondary server's SQL agent job in AG Group still able to run cause script run twice

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, sql-agent-job

We have a AG Group setup for 2 server A (Primary) ,B (Secondary)
A,B have identical setup for sql agent job

A job run successful and
B job's failed in initial step when trying to access the db (Due to The target database , is participating in an availability group and is currently not accessible for queries.)

Once A failover and B become Primary. We notice a behaviour that A & B sql agent Job also running successfully, so the job run twice.

We tried to modify script in sql agent Job, by adding printing @@servername variable, we found that A & B sql agent job are also printing B(now is primary) servername. Likely 2 job are also running in B(primary) server.

The only way to resolve is currently just to restart the sql agent service. Would like to know if any other solution?

SQL server version is 13.0.5888.11

Below Issue is similar to mine, but no solution yet
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433964/sql-server-ag-agent-jobs-running-successfully-on-secondary-replica][1]

Comment: When I've run in this configuration, I either had a job step that tested whether or not the target database was the primary or not (and, to be explicit, I like looking at `databasepropertyex('yourDb', 'Updateability')` as it also accounts for non-AG databases) and bail if it's not the primary. Do your jobs discriminate at all between primary and secondary?

Comment: I tried to add this in this script, the situation after failover (B primary, A secondary), A's job agent triggered job is showing B's servername, and databasepropertyex('yourDb', 'Updateability') return 'READ_WRITE', i think A's job are running with B server so secondary server also run, and cause duplicate.

Comment: What is the job step doing? If it's a T-SQL job step that runs against the local instance (i.e. no linked servers involved, no calls to xp_cmdshell to get to sqlcmd or similar, etc), I don't understand how you're getting to the primary replica. If you believe that that is indeed the case (i.e. it's only accessing resources local to the replica), come up with a minimally reproducible example. That is, a job that only a) tries to determine replica state and b) does something simple (e.g. only `select @@servername`).

Comment: Thanks Ben, It is a T-SQL step job, I tried to use simple method like @@servername to determine where it execute, both job showing is from primary replica at same time. It is a weird behaviour.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server AG Agent jobs running successfully on secondary replica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433964/sql-server-ag-agent-jobs-running-successfully-on-secondary-replica)

Answer (score 0):

If I want to run a script as a job I run it inside the below script.
It checks if the status of the AOAG preferred replica is true.

It works for my needs but be aware, as a job it will complete as successful on the secondary but will not run the script inside the `Begin/End`!

```
USE [master];
GO

DECLARE @preferredReplica int

SET @preferredReplica = (SELECT [master].sys.fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica('DBName'))  --*your DBname here*

IF (@preferredReplica = 1)  -- *true result*

BEGIN

/* *SQL script here* */

END
```